# Use JQuery to dynamically load thousands of rows into table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, oracle, datatables

I'm working on a front-facing GUI for a CRM. We have a tiered structure of customers. Each customer has many addresses that they bill to, many addresses that they ship-to, and many contacts associated with each account. The issue I'm having is that some customers have well over 10,000 ship-to's associated with the account. This becomes a problem when calling for all of them at once. I have the backend fine, it gets all of the ship-to data in ~280ms (on average.) I'm using Javascript to load all of the information into the table. Here's what I'm doing currently:

```
    var r = new Array();
var j = -1, recordID;
r[++j] = '';

    //Loop through the data and build an array.
    for (i in data) {
        var d = data[i];
            recordID = d.id;
        r[++j] = '<tr>';
        r[++j] = '<td>'+ d['ADDRESS_LINE_1'] +'</td>';
        r[++j] = '</tr>';
    }
    //The line below joins the array and appends it to the table.
    $('#table').append(r.join(''));
```

I've talked with the people who build the specs for me, and they **need** all of them to show at once, there's no possibility of filtering. Right now it's taking ~4s before all of the data is loaded and the modal opens.

*Is there a faster way to do this?*

Comment: it's impossible to have all the rows shown at once unless they have a really big screen. just load more on scroll. don't render 10K records if only 100 fit on the screen.

Comment: Take a look at DataTables https://datatables.net/

Comment: So is the problem that the data is loading too slowly?

Comment: @Brian OP should also look at https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

If you're not keen on using datatables, you need to come up with your own mechanism of loading handful of data at a time, with a pagination system. Which is already done for you by datatables. Approach to this is simple however, i.e. Load 50 pieces of data. User requests More, Load Another 50.

Comment: Some good points here. Datatables was my first approach, but it was too slow, I'll look at defer_render. Is there a way I can save the data as an array, and call array values #0-50, and when scrolling to #51, load #50-100? If that's something that's possible, that'd be ideal.

Comment: have you try something like table sorter or ui-grid from angular?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.map(yourArrayVar, function(value, key) {
   return '<TR><TD>'+value['ADDRESS_LINE_1']+'</TD></TR>';
});
$("#table").append(yourArrayVar.join(''));
```

This could help you in a better performance than looping.
Know more on it here, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: The OP is still creating thousands of dom elements at once.